# google cloud function not uploading to bucket but no error in function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a NodeJS function that writes several small svg files locally and then is attempting to upload those files to cloud bucket.
in the function log, i am only seeing the message that file written to local disk. now will upload. But there is no file in the bucket and no error logged anywhere. i have made sure the timeout is set to 9 min (max) so i am sure its not timing out. what else shoudl i check?

any pointers will be appreciated.

```
exports.createQRCode = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) =>{


  const qrcodeMonkeyKey = functions.config().qrcodemonkey.key;
  //console.log(`key for qrcode monkey is ${qrcodeMonkeyKey}`);
  

  const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
  const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
  const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
  const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.

  console.log(fileBucket);
  console.log(filePath);
  if(!filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith('.csv'))
    return console.log('not a csv so no need to anything fancy');

  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);

  const filePathComps = filePath.split('/');
  const folderName = filePathComps[filePathComps.length-3];
  if(folderName !== "qrcode")
    return console.log('not a qr code csv so no need to anything fancy');
  const fileName = filePathComps[filePathComps.length-1];
  console.log(fileName);

  const path = require('path');
  const os = require('os');
  const fs = require('fs');

  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
  const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
  };
  await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath});

  const csv = require('csv-parser')
  const results = [];
  fs.createReadStream(tempFilePath)
  .pipe(csv({headers:
      ['uri','filename','foldername']
       ,skipLines:1
         }))
         .on('data',  async (data) => {
          const x = data;
          results.push(data);

          //results.push({id:x.id,phoneNumber:x.phoneNumber,isInternational:x.isInternational,message:x.messageText,respStatus:resp.status,responsedata:resp.data});       
      })
      .on('end',async () => {

          pArray = [];
          results.forEach(x =>{
            pArray.push(createQRCodeAndUpload(qrcodeMonkeyKey,x.filename,x.uri,x.foldername));
        });
        
        const finaloutput =  await Promise.all(pArray);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(finaloutput));
        return;
      });



});

const createQRCodeAndUpload = async (qrcodeMonkeyKey,fileName, url,foldername) =>{
 
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('vmallapp.appspot.com');
  const path = require('path');
  const os = require('os');
  const fs = require('fs');
  var axios = require("axios").default;
  console.log('processing ' + url);
  if(url !==""){
  const dataToSend = {
      data : url,
      config :{
          body:'circle',
          eye:'frame14',
          eyeBall:'ball16',
          bodyColor:"#032b5c",
          bgColor:"#84d4e2",
          "logo":"ae600e1267b9e477f0b635b60ffaec1d1c18d93b.png"
      },
      size:1200,
      download:false,
      file:'svg',
      gradientOnEyes:true
  }


  var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com/qr/custom',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': qrcodeMonkeyKey
      },
      data: dataToSend
    };

    var response = await axios.request(options);
    console.log('qrcode monkey returned status' + response.status);

    const outputFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), `${fileName}.svg`);
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, response.data);
    console.log(`${fileName}.svg written to local disk. now will upload`);
    try{
    await bucket.upload(outputFilePath, {
      destination: `qrcode/output/${fileName}.svg`
    });
    }catch(error){
      console.log('error in uploding ' + error);
    }
    console.log('lets delete the file now and clean up local storage');
    fs.unlinkSync(outputFilePath);
    return 'all done';
  }
    

}
```

Comment: Can you share the complete function and logs? Also you say 'several svgs' but it seems you are uploading 1.

Comment: I recommend looking at the logs generated by your function.

Comment: @Dharmaraj edited the function to include all code. the other csv that is being read will have lots of lines..

Comment: it does not generate any log. just dies silently.